# killing a non-terminating process in a loop

Tags: java, java-threads

I am processing images using a pure-java "blackBox", representable by:

```
imageOut = imageProcess(imageIn);
```

This is in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    imageOut[i] = imageProcess(imageIn[i]);
}
```

Almost all processes terminate in 2-5 seconds, but a few (perhaps 2%) run for many minutes and some don't appear to terminate (I don't know why). I would like to terminate these after (say) 30 secs, record the pathological image, and move to the next. The blackBox has no i/o, but also no way of embedding `Thread.isInterrupted()`, etc.

Can I use `Thread.stop()` to kill the process after 30 seconds? and if so how do I do this? [I realise it has been deprecated, but I can't find another way.] Alternatively is there a better way to tackle the problem, without modifying `imageProcess()`?

In essence I'd like to run this as a filter: "Reject all images that take longer than 30seconds processing".

UPDATE:
Following Peter Lawrey I am exploring `ProcessBuilder`.

He posted a simple solution for Java >=1.8 which I have accepted. Since I am currently on Java 1.7 I have posted my own answer which works for a simple case in earlier versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to start a new process using ProcessBuilder.  When this process times out you can call `destroy()` on it and know all the resources will be cleaned up. (Except perhaps temporary files)

Comment: Just to check... I need to create a commandline and call each process through `main()`, and pass data through arguments?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust Correct. It's a bit of a pain, but gives you complete isolation.

Comment: I already have almost all this in place - commandline interpreter, etc. -, so it's not a problem. Where do I set the timer? I couldn't see anything in `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: The process runs in the background.  You can use `Process.waitFor(x, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to wait for a process and destroy it if it hasn't finished.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful but I can't find a `waitFor()` with arguments in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html . I will try yours in case it's later than Java 7.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust Yes, The Javadoc for this method says "since 1.8" ;)

Comment: Accepting your answer. I will also post my own hack for Java <1.8 based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Lawrey has posted an answer for Java 1.8. Using his general approach I have created the following code for <1.8. I have tested this and it works (on my Mac OSX):

```
    public void testProcess() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // create a process which runs for a second
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sleep", "1");
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        // test it every 100 milliseconds
        Thread.sleep(100); // 100 millisec
        int exitValue = -1;
        try {
            exitValue = process.exitValue();
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            // this is thrown if the process has not yet terminated
            System.out.println("step: "+i);
            continue;
        }
        // process has exited
        if (exitValue == 0) {
            System.out.println("final steps: "+i);
            break;
        }
    }
    // destroy() process in all cases
    process.destroy();  
}
```

Comment: Have tested this in a production run and am pleased to say that it works in a large loop (many hundreds of images with no apparent problems.

Comment: Note that since my application is effectively a command line for the main program it loads the program for every iteration. Since there are > 4secs between instances maybe that isn't a problem, but it seems to work the machine very hard.